# How to convert a List<List<String>> to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I have a method which builds a `List<List<String>>` object. I need to convert this list to type `Object[][]` and return it. I couldn't do this, when I add an `Object[]` to a list all the array elements are added as individual objects.

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
list.add(new Object[2]{"A", "B"});
return list.toArray();
```

From the above example, `return list.toArray()` is returning `Object[]` not `Object[][]` though it was declared as `List<Object[]>`;

Please help to get `Object[][]` from `List<List<String>>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest approach may be to stream the list, and handle sub-list individually:

```
List<List<String>> list = /* something */
Object[][] result = 
    list.stream()
        .map(List::toArray)
        .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the array type you want to convert it to.

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
list.add(new Object[] { "A", "B" });
list.add(new Object[] { "C", "D" });
Object[][] o = list.toArray(new Object[][] {});

for (Object[] o1 : o) {
    for (Object o2 : o1) {
        System.out.print(o2 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This codes output is:

```
A B 
C D
```